# Can I edit and apply tomcat setting (conf/server.xml,context.xml) without restart tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, context.xml, server.xml

I`m trying to change tomcat settings (conf/server.xml, context.xml) without restarting tomcat in k8s, to maintaining Pod container status. If I restart tomcat, Pod would be shut down and newer settings will be lost.

So I need solution applying settings without restart tomcat. Is there any way to do this?

(I don't consider applying new settings in yaml files, trying to edit dynamically)

Answer (score 2):

If you change server.xml you have to restart Tomcat.

If you change the global context.xml, web.xml or the per host or per web application equivalents and automatic deployment is enabled, Tomcat will reload/redploy the web application as appropriate.

There are a lot of combinations and the full set describing what will happen with each is described in the [Tomcat documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/config/automatic-deployment.html)

Comment: thanks, i  had tried to find the way not to restart it after change xml. but there was no way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I've not deployed to Tomcat directly in a while (I tend to use Spring Boots integrated tomcat) However I can tell you it wasn't previously possible to have changes to the Server configuration reflected without restarting.